# increase the data limit Increasing Limit of max.print in R

Tags: r, csv, import

How can I increase the data limit in R Studio?

R Warning: [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 11451374 rows ]

My data limit is about 15268500, I options(max.print = 15268500). after running the code the imported data was only 3817125 and the same error appeared? Any suggestions to import the whole data?

Regards

Comment: It is unclear what you want to actually achieve. You certainly don't want to print a few million rows of data. There are no circumstances where that could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.      Its just the first step analysis